# Tecplot: eight node quadrilaterals

Tags: nodes

I am using tecplot to plot FE mesh. It has an option of plotting four node quadrilaterals using FEQUADRILATERAL zone type. I want to plot a 2D eight node quadrilateral with four corner nodes and four mid nodes (one on each side of the quadrilateral). I have the following X and Y coordinates for the eight nodes. I have never used tecplot before, can any one help me with this.

```
Node1  0    0
Node2  1    0
Node3  1    1
Node4  0    1
Node5  0.5  0
Node6  1    0.5 
Node7  0.5   1
Node8  0    0.5
```

I am not able to find correct tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of doing this is to convert your 8node quad to a 4node quad by converting one eight node quad to four 4 node quads.You would just need to add the cell center point to your data set and averaging the stresses and displacement to find the values at the mid node.

or

Inside tecplot Data Format guide take a look at the section on Polyhedral data.  Read through Chapter 3 Section 8, this should explain how you need to format the data.  eight node quads can be plotted using polyhedral